# PHP file is not running, permission issue

Tags: php, apache, file-permissions

I am using Linux Mint 19.1. I installed Apache and PHP. I put `info.php` file in `/var/www/html/`.

[image]

I run `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/` for permission.

My `info.php` file is like below

```
<?php
 echo phpinfo();
?>
```

But I am getting blank white page.

[image]

Comment: Not an answer but remove the `echo`, you don't need it. Also make sure you can see any errors, including PHP startup errors.

Comment: Thanks @Phil, I am getting same result.

Comment: How did you _"install Apache and PHP"_? Perhaps you've installed each thing but they're not configured to work together

Comment: Thanks @Phil, I followed this tutorial. https://linux4one.com/how-to-install-php-7-2-on-linux-mint-19/?fbclid=IwAR2CilOznhpiQ5LwspLVcf68kGEE-XFMnp1FJVx9JD_9GxuYUjaEkG1lpq8

Comment: Can index.html or `echo '123'` be shown?

Comment: Thanks @shingo. I can see https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2SME.png.